# Generate Code for MS SQL Database Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema

I don't know if I am using the correct terminology here.

I want to recreate the tables of a local database on my computer on another one. I do not care about duplicating the data stored, but just the tables, their relationships, constraints etc.

I have been using Microsoft SQL 2012. Is there a way to generate the SQL code that defines my tables. (What I would have typed to set up my tables had I not done it graphically)

Comment: If you're fine with using the SQL Server Management Studio tool you can right click a table and use `Script Table as/CREATE To`to generate the sql code needed to recreate it.

Comment: Right click your database, choose Tasks, then Generate Scripts.

Comment: @jpw Thanks. That's all I needed. You can write that as an answer (although the question was very trivial)

Comment: @Andomar you're answer is actually even better.

Comment: @user929404 Andomars answer is better than mine. I had totally forgot that option...